# Why do we need reactjs-bootstrap if there's easy way?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I've been developing web app using react or angular but I'm confused why people would use library like react-bootstrap (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/introduction.html) or Angular-bootstrap? Because when I create I just have to load the css framework using link tag with its corresponding js lib, then in reactjs side, I just have to put the classes needed for a component. Isn't that sounds easier?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the Javascript portion of Bootstrap. The CSS will work just fine with a link tag.

But React and Angular are Javascript libraries which have a lot under the hood for manipulating the DOM. If you also use something like Bootstrap or jQuery to manipulate the DOM, it probably won't play well with React or Angular since they're trying to do similar things in very different ways maybe at the same time. So DOM-related Javascript libraries need to be rewritten so they play nicely with React/Angular.

From the react-bootstrap docs:

> we don't ship with any included css

All they deal with is the JS.

Comment: Is that so? I've been working with them, but everything seems to be just fine. Like how the menu will work, and any other css component that uses js. Also one of my concern is it seems that the development of those libraries are delayed or I cannot use just any version of bootstrap I want to use.

Comment: From Facebook: 

*React is unaware of changes made to the DOM outside of React. It determines updates based on its own internal representation, and if the same DOM nodes are manipulated by another library, React gets confused and has no way to recover.*

*This does not mean it is impossible or even necessarily difficult to combine React with other ways of affecting the DOM, you just have to be mindful of what each are doing.* 

So only if you know the specifics of how your DOM libraries manipulate things and are able to code around that to prevent any unexpected results, use them.

Comment: Okay, I'm enlightened. I like both of your answers but number 2 gives me the idea that not because it's running must be the right thing to do. I always want the best practice out there as a software developer. I'll use them from now on. Thank you.

Comment: Sure! Like the quote from Facebook says, you can certainly use two or more DOM-manipulation libraries together. But they very easily may compete with each other in unexpected ways, so you may as well use a library out there that handles all of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you chose to work with `reactjs` you chose a library that updates your DOM in a cleaver and sophisticate way.
It has the virtual DOM and bunch of algorithms (like the [Diffing algorithm](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html)) to determine when and how to update the DOM in the most fast and efficient and performant way.

When you combine this with another library that updates the DOM, you basically interrupt those algorithms to do their job.
Beside performance aspects, you are working against the pattern of react, you break the "component pattern".
`React-Bootstrap` is here to help you maintain your component pattern with their components. you just need to include the `css` and other resource files.
Their components doesn't do anything beside rendering HTML with proper class names that correspond to the classes that in the bootstrap's css files.
They do that in the same way all your other components do it, via `props`.
This way you can have a bootstrap components that play nice with your other components in a native way without breaking the pattern.

Yeah, it's easier to dump some `css` and `js` files and things just works, but it's harder to maintain, debug and scale.